# Animation not correct when bound to a visibility property(Oddity)

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, mvvm, visibility

The issue that I'm having is that any time I change a visibility property to trigger a loading animation (i.g. isBusy = true) via a command in the MVVM model the animation doesn't play out correctly. The results are random during run time, sometimes the animation is very near flawless, sometimes it only gets half way through and then loops.

In either case it always takes exactly the length of the storyboard to do this behavior (i.g. it will rotate a random amount of degrees, ignoring the storyboard, but always take .5 seconds to complete.)

The weird thing is that if I trigger the isBusy from a constructor the animation works flawlessly, but if I call it via a commandExecute it breaks. Examples of the code and my XAML below.

```
        <Grid x:Name="LoadingGrid"  Visibility="{Binding isBusy, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <LoadingViews:LoadingView x:Name="LoadingControl" />
    </Grid>
```

C#:

```
        public StoreSearchViewModel(MainViewModel mainViewModel)
    {
        this.mainViewModel = mainViewModel;
        mainViewModel.LogUsage("Store Search");

        searchResultsCommand = new DelegateCommand(SearchResultsCommandExecute);
        storeSearchCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(SetBusy, CanStoreSearchCommandExecute);
        CloseWindowCommand = new DelegateCommand(CloseWindowExecute);
        Setup();

    }

        private void SetBusy(object obj)
    {
        isBusy = true;
    }

    private bool _isBusy;
    public bool isBusy
    {
        get { return _isBusy; }
        set { _isBusy= value; OnPropertyChanged("isBusy"); }
    }
```

The above code will result in a glitched loading animation, where the animation lives in the grid, whose visibility is determined by isBusy, and triggered by a command in the view. The command being triggered is storeSearchCommand.

However the below code will produce good animation.

```
        private void Setup()
    {
        //create view models
        _storeSearchResultsViewModel = new StoreSearchResultsViewModel(this);

        //set default selection to the dashboard
        isStoreSearchResultsSelected = true;
        SearchResultsCommandExecute();
        SetBusy();
    }
```

Please note that the "object obj" is just me passing the required params to test the code. Please disregard any inconsistencies with that passed object.

I've racked my brain on this for a while and simply cannot figure it out.

Comment: Please, post the code for the CanStoreSearchCommandExecute.

Comment: CanStoreSearchCommandExecute only checks to make sure that the object being passed matches some requirements. It shouldn't impact the loading animation in any way. (it would outright prevent code from running and no animation would play at all if something failed the validation)

Comment: Alright, can you post a zip file of the test project so I can try to get the same results on my machine? I tried here with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue myself by building the animation locally instead of referencing a different view which contained the animation.

Before:

```
<Grid x:Name="LoadingGrid"  Visibility="{Binding isBusy, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.RowSpan="2">
    <LoadingViews:LoadingView x:Name="LoadingControl" />
</Grid>
```

Now:

```
    <Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard1" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[2].(RotateTransform.Angle)">
            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01" Value="360"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Storyboard1}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>

        <ContentControl x:Name="CurrentViewContentControl" Content="{Binding currentView, Mode=TwoWay}" Background="#FFDC00FF" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <Grid x:Name="LoadingGrid"  Visibility="{Binding isBusy, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" Grid.RowSpan="2" d:IsHidden="True">
        <Grid.Background>
            <RadialGradientBrush>
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#BF000000" Offset="1"/>
            </RadialGradientBrush>
        </Grid.Background>
        <Grid Margin="446,285">

            <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse" StrokeThickness="6" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                <Ellipse.Effect>
                    <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="3"/>
                </Ellipse.Effect>
                <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform/>
                        <SkewTransform/>
                        <RotateTransform/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                <Ellipse.Stroke>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.445,0.997" StartPoint="0.555,0.003">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF0244D1"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#00000000" Offset="0.313"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF0244D1" Offset="0.063"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Ellipse.Stroke>
            </Ellipse>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Probably not very clean, since I have this exact animation built elsewhere in the project, but at least it animates properly now.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because of using some long time code running in the UI thread.
Let's consider an example.

1. You clicked on some button.
2. That button execute some command.
3. That command runs in the UI thread by default.
4. That command sets isBusy = true than do some "long" work.

In the UI you will see starting some animation (that is bind to isBusy property) only when our command riched the end of its long code running.
It is just an example.

So, you should use async call. It means, set isBusy = true, do some code in the separate thread. And you could see changes of isBusy property almost immediately.

Here is an example:

```
        isBusy = true;
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                //do some code. It is a new thread
            }).ContinueWith((x) =>
            {
                //do some code after previous task is done. This code runs in the UI thread
                isBusy = false;
            }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Comment: I should also point out that for the purpose of testing code the only thing I'm doing is setting the property of isBusy to true. Some my code flow is "Trigger command - > Set isBusy to true" and no code after that. In effect it should trigger and permanently leave up the animation since I'm never setting it back to false, or running any code in the background.